# How can I make my Quaterion.RotateTowards() not rotate instantly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I didn't think that far ahead as I was focused on fixing my x-axis mouse clamp, and now I can't make my `Quaternion.RotateTowards` rotate slower. When I enter a trigger, the code below which is inside the `Update` method of my MouseLook/Camera script activates for a different kind of mouse movement.

```
[Range(0f, 90f)][SerializeField] float xRotationLimit = 35f;

void Update()
    {
        transform.position = player.position + offset;

        if (trigger.clampRotation)
        {
            clampHorizontalRotation();
        }
        else
        {
            NormalCameraMovement();
        }
    }

void clampHorizontalRotation() 
{
Vector2 mouseDelta = Input.GetAxis(xAxis) * Vector2.right + Input.GetAxis(yAxis) * Vector2.up;

rotation.x += mouseDelta.x * sensitivity;
rotation.y += mouseDelta.y * sensitivity;

rotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(rotation.y, -yRotationLimit, yRotationLimit);

var yQuat = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotation.y, Vector3.left);

var xQuat = Quaternion.RotateTowards(climbing.CubeObj.rotation, Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotation.x, Vector3.up), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

rotation.x = xQuat.eulerAngles.y;

transform.localRotation = yQuat;
player.transform.localRotation = xQuat;
}

void NormalCameraMovement()
{
    // Normal mouse movement goes here
}
```

The issue is the `var xQuat` line with the `RotateTowards`. The reason for my code the way it is with `Quaternion.AngleAxis` inside the `Quaternion.RotateTowards`, is to prevent gimbal lock. But now when I enter the trigger of the "CubeObj", my player instantly rotates towards it, rather than slowly.

What should happen in real time is: I walk up to my trigger object (CubeObject) and then my player automatically rotates slowly towards the CubeObject, so that my player is facing it. From there, my vertical axis is clamped (which is easy) and my x-axis mouse rotation is also clamped so that I cannot move left or right beyond a certain degrees.

Comment: Try decreasing `xRotationLimit` dramatically!

Comment: @asj Since the code is inside my Update, even if I decrease that variable dramatically, it will continuously decrease the variable and then reset every frame right? So basically it'll be an infinite loop. Is there a way to only have it decrease once and not reset? Because I've tried for example `xRotationLimit--` and also `xRotationLimit -= 5f` which works, but then I get this very super fast infinite camera spinning effect, as if my mouse sensitivity has been set to 10000. So if I even touch my mouse while in the trigger, that effect will occur.

Comment: @derHugo The code in my post is basically mouse movement. I have two mouse movements, one for when OnTriggerEnter activates (like you see in the post) and then my normal movement which is not shown. How the code above works is, if I am not facing the trigger object but OnTriggerEnter has activated, my player will automatically rotate towards it, to which then x-axis clamp of ‘xRotationLimit’ will take effect immediately after. I can create a gif as well to show how it works and then the issue I get with the solutions provided

Comment: As said show your full code .. currently it is hard to tell what exactly is being called how and when and where it fails

Comment: I put my full code into my post 4 hours ago so it's all there now, with an additional comment at the very bottom of this page in response to the other person

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html): `public static Quaternion RotateTowards(Quaternion from, Quaternion to, float maxDegreesDelta);`

"The `from` quaternion is rotated towards `to` by an angular step of `maxDegreesDelta`. [This happens each time this function is called!]"

Thus, you want to decrease `maxDegreesDelta`.

Keep in mind that if you run this function in `Update` it may happen 60 times a second, assuming a framerate of 60. Thus if you set `maxDegreesDelta` to a number as small as `1`, you still get up to `60°` of rotation in just a second. That's pretty fast considering an entire rotation is only `360°`!

Now if you just started building your game, you may get framerates up to 300 FPS. Thus allowing for up to `300°` of rotation in a second, making your rotations look instant.

Start with a very small number like `0.01`. Now multiply it with `Time.deltaTime` to make it consistent across devices. Then, if it's rotating too slow, up the value from there. Add it as a public or serialized float and play around with the speed in the inspector in Play Mode until you are satisfied. Take note of the 'right' value and then apply that value when you're *not* in PlayMode.

Comment: But my `xRotationLimit` is also responsible for my x-axis clamping, which is why I have it set to 35f and if I attempt to multiply it by any value, the horizontal mouse movement stops working. Where would I try to multiply it?

Comment: You could just make a different variable for the `rotationSpeed` and use that in place of the `xRotationLimit`? Then you can keep using your `xRotationLimit` for the clamp code.

Comment: I updated the code in my post to match what I currently have. The `rotationSpeed` works perfectly, but there is still no x-axis camera/mouse rotation possible at all. I replaced `xRotationLimit` with `rotationSpeed` but now I don't know where to add `xRotationLimit` because I can't add a quaternion (`xQuat`) to Mathf.Clamp. My only thought was maybe something like this right underneath the `RotateTowards` line: `rotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(xQuat, -xRotationLimit, xRotationLimit);` which I know isn't possible due to the Quaternion 'cannot convert to float' error

Comment: I usually try to resolve rotational clamping issues by converting the rotation to `localEulerAngles`, storing the result into a nes var, and then setting the `localEulerAngles` to that new var, while  `Mathf.Clamp`ing the axis that I want the limits on.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is wrong

```
var xQuat = Quaternion.RotateTowards(climbing.CubeObj.rotation, Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotation.x, Vector3.up), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

you here get a rotation from the `climbing.rotation` towards the `Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotation.x, Vector3.up)`. Since the `climbing.CubeObj.rotation` doesn't change this will always be more or less the same rotation assuming the mouse didn't move.

=> You do not rotate smooth towards a target rotation here! You only smooth out the target direction itself but still immediately snap to it.

---

If I understand correctly what you actually want is to clamp your rotation around the X axis to be 35° around the rotation of `climbing.CubeObj`.

Then you rather want to smoothly rotate your player to this target rotation.

So your target rotation should probably be something like e.g.

```
rotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(rotation.x, -xRotationLimit, xRotationLimit);
// This is now a rotation within 35 degrees from the climbing.CubeObj.rotation
var xQuat = climbing.CubeObj.rotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotation.x, Vector3.up);
```

and then

```
// In general: careful with mixing local and global rotations
// this now smoothly rotates the player towards the target rotation 
player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(player.transform.rotation, xQuat, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: I actually previously used the update `var xQuat` line that you provided however I couldn't make it work. What happens currently (prior to this post) is that when I enter the trigger of the Cube Object (a ladder), my character instantly rotates towards it, and from there I get  35 degree x-axis clamp. What happens when I update all my code now to this is that I can't move my mouse on the x-axis at all, and then when I exit trigger, my rotation snaps forward

Answer (score 0):

You could *try* lerping (interpolate) the rotation by a set speed instead:

```
[SerializeField] 
private float rotationSpeed = 5f;

// ...

void clampHorizontalRotation()
{
    Vector2 mouseDelta = Input.GetAxis(xAxis) * Vector2.right + Input.GetAxis(yAxis) * Vector2.up;

    rotation.x += mouseDelta.x * sensitivity;
    rotation.y += mouseDelta.y * sensitivity;

    rotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(rotation.y, -yRotationLimit, yRotationLimit);

    var yQuat = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotation.y, Vector3.left);

    Quaternion targetXRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotation.x, Vector3.up);
    // Slerp between the current rotation to the target rotation..
    player.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(climbing.CubeObj.rotation, targetXRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    transform.localRotation = yQuat;
    // To match the player's rotation as well...
    rotation.x = player.transform.localEulerAngles.y;

    // When rotation angle reaches extremely close,
    // just snap it to the target.
    if (Quaternion.Angle(climbing.CubeObj.rotation, targetXRotation) < 0.1f)
    {
        climbing.CubeObj.rotation = targetXRotation;
    }
}
```

*Also, it would help a lot to show your whole code, so that we can replicate the problem*

Comment: I actually completely altered my code and I took out the entire rotation portion, so now my clamp works, however the one issue I have is that if I am climbing a ladder that is NOT rotated at the default (0,0,0), my camera will snap to my x-axis rotation clamp value if that makes sense. I can attach my code in a pastebin if that helps.